# create setup for windows service c#

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have created a c# windows service 
when I put my visual studio in debug mode and I run it , it works correctly 
but when I create a setup and install it , it doesn't work(means the service installed correctly and start but my code doesn't running).
(I built setup like this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816169)
this is my Code:
 This is my Code : dropbox.com/s/eq13fng88gk714u/myTelephone.zip?dl=0

```
 static class Program

        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>
            static void Main()
            {


    #if DEBUG
                myTelephone myService1 = new myTelephone();
                myService1.onDebug();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

    #else


               ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                { 
                    new myTelephone() 
                };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

    #endif
    }
```

And

```
  public partial class myTelephone : ServiceBase
    {
        public myTelephone()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }   public void onDebug()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            //////save some data in sql server
}}
```

Comment: Where is SQL server touched in question? Remove tag if not necessery.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you have any error? Stacktrace?

Comment: I don't have any error , I'm sure because in debug mode when I run my program it works correctly and save my data in sql server

Comment: Please read [ask] and elaborate on "does not work". Check the event log for errors.

Comment: Do you have Installer in your project? Look here about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes, I added installer :(

Comment: How do you add your service into Windows Service manager?

Comment: This is my Code : https://www.dropbox.com/s/eq13fng88gk714u/myTelephone.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Did you even try to google this before asking?

Anyways, just use Topshelf via nuget. This way you always execute the same code when debugging and when it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide anything except of 'it does not work', I'll try to assume:

1. either your Windows service is not being installed - then see the 'your service executable'.exe.InstallLog file in the same folder where 'your service executable' is located;
2. or the Windows service was installed successfully but it doesn't start - then go to the Event Viewer and look for the error message there related to your service. If that's the case then most probably that's because your OnStart method goes to timeout. In this case:

Either request additional time inside the method:

```cs
    // request additional 4 seconds for the start-up process
    this.RequestAdditionalTime(4000);
```

or move the code that access the SQL database out of the method, for example, creating a new thread and doing all your staff there.

Comment: 'it does not work' means the service installed correctly and start but my code doesn't running

Comment: This is my Code : dropbox.com/s/eq13fng88gk714u/myTelephone.zip?dl=0

Comment: Did you try to attach the debugger to the service from Visual Studio? Unfortunately I don't have access to dropbox from my current location, so no way to see your code there...

Comment: can I have your email?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to install this by clickicg exe file. It is not correct.
Try next:

1. Open cmd
2. cd to directory with myTelephone.exe
3. run next

   sc create myTelephone binpath= "myTelephone.exe" start= auto

   net start myTelephone

Or you also could do add to pre-build event:

```
net stop $(ProjectName)
sc delete $(ProjectName)
exit /b 0
```

As post-build event:

```
sc create $(ProjectName) binpath= "$(TargetPath)" start= auto
net start $(ProjectName)
```

And on each build you will have installed service.

Comment: This is an extremely bad workflow for developing services, and not an answer to OP's question at all. OP wants to add an installer to their service project.

Comment: It is way to try workability of service. As I understand from discussio OP added Installer to project.

Comment: It is a horrible way to debug services. There exist many ways that do this better.

Comment: ОК, suggest it! It's better than criticize